# Rebuild array from output of select command

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, jq

I have to select objects in an array according a test pattern

I apply the following command:

```
jq '.[] | select(.path | test("a/b") | not)'
```

to the following object

```
[
   {
      path: "a/b"
   },
   {
      path: "a/b/c"
   },
   {
      path: "a/c"
   },
   {
      path: "a/d"
   }
]
```

My problem is that the result is not anymore an array but a list of objects. I have tried to do the most obvious thing which is to pipe the command to `map(.)` but I get the following result:

```
[
  "a/c"
]
[
  "a/d"
]
```

Comment: `jq 'map(select(.path | test("a/b") | not))'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By starting the pipeline with `.[]`, you are converting the array into a stream.  You could "reconstitute" the array by wrapping the entire jq expression in square brackets (i.e. `[ .... ]`); or you could avoid using `.[]` in the first place by using `map( select(...) )`.

(Since `map(f)` is implemented as `[.[] | f]` it doesn't make much difference which method you choose except perhaps on stylistic grounds.  One could argue that `map` is more appropriate for a functional style, whereas `[.[] ... ]` is less biased towards English.)